# take video snapshot from ffmpeg on other server in php

Tags: php, ffmpeg, snapshot

I use ffmpeg for take video snapshot.
It works correctly in localhost but when video is on other host it does not work correctly and don't show error.

**This is my code.**

```
$videos_file_name='http://test.com/test.mp4'
$cmd = "ffmpeg -i $videos_file_name -an -y -f mjpeg  -ss 00:00:04 -vframes 1 source/$image_file";
return exec($cmd);
```

Comment: I removed the ffmpeg-php from your question. The ffmpeg-php tag is for questions about the php-extension, not for calling ffmpeg with exec.

Comment: You also should include how you want to access the video on the other host (content of `$videos_file_name`) and also the whole output of ffmpeg. It does not work is not an error ;)

Comment: thanks. I update my post.

Comment: What is the output of the ffmpeg call?

Comment: null ................

Comment: I mean if you call it directly on the command line, not in php

Comment: in cmd it work correctly